# progress bar in background worker get argument which being updated in the main thread c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have the main thread which is wizard in WPF.

after user finished set the properties of the wizard, it processing data.

It takes a few seconds and I would like to raise a progress bar which report on the progress.

Hence, I set always on the main thread variable call currentStep.

I have totally thresholdStep steps which equals to 12.

So I want that the progress bar will work as a thread but it will also will be connected to the main thread by using currentStep variable.

So, I used by background worker like this:

```
public partial class MessageWithProgressBar : Window
{
    private BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    public MessageWithProgressBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += ProgressChanged;
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += DoWork;
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    }

    private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        int i = (int)e.Argument;
        backgroundWorker.ReportProgress((int)Math.Floor((decimal)(8*i)));
        if (i > GeneralProperties.General.thresholdStep)
            backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(100);
    }

    private void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        WindowMsg msg = new WindowMsg();
        msg.Show();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker.IsBusy == false)
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(GeneralProperties.General.currentStep);
    }
}
```

In addition, I called the background worker from the main thread as below:

```
MessageWithProgressBar progress = new MessageWithProgressBar();
progress.Show();
```

What acutally happens is that DoWork called only once with currentStep = 1 and it don't updates in relation to the main thread which also updated currentStep dependents on it's progress.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Haven't you forgotten `backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(YourArgument);`

Comment: @NawedNabiZada See Window_Loaded method in my question

Comment: Correct.. I was a little too fast I guess. You are starting your background worker only once when the window loads. And it only setting the progress at one point.

Comment: @NawedNabiZada So, how to solve it? what you suggests?

Comment: First of all I have to understand the problem. You have some data which has to be processed, and it is processed in a background thread ? And it it is done in 12 steps ? is that correct ?

Comment: @NawedNabiZada I have some data which has to be processes and it is processed in the main thread (no in the second thread) and it is done in 12 steps. the background thread hold progress bar and shall be updated according variable which the main thread maintenance.

Comment: That's a very odd way of doing it. Normally you would do your data processing in the background, (in main thread your UI will be frozen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `DoWork` method like below:

```
 private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        int i = (int)e.Argument;
        do
        {   
            i = GeneralProperties.General.currentStep;
            backgroundWorker.ReportProgress((int)Math.Floor((decimal)(8 * i)));
            if (i > GeneralProperties.General.thresholdStep)
               backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(100);
        }
        while (i < GeneralProperties.General.thresholdStep);
    }
```

Just make sure your are not getting thread `synchronization` problem with `GeneralProperties.General` object, if you are then use `lock` when accessing the object.

***UPDATE:***

For update problem:

```
 private void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            progress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }), null);
    }
```

Comment: now it inserted to infinite loop, since i remains always 1

Comment: @Programmer it means GeneralProperties.General.currentStep is not updating, which was supposed to by main thrad. try checking the values in debug mode

Comment: I chcecked it and found in Debug mode that it doesn't insert to infinite loop but doesn't insert to BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted event after i >= GeneralProperties.General.thresholdStep

Comment: @Programmer you meant that at a point the loop breaks(which is as expected) but background worker's RunWorkerCompleted delegate method  never got executed after that. Am I right?

Comment: I added the condition in DoWork event:
 if (i > GeneralProperties.General.thresholdStep)
                return;
And now it's working.. 
The only issue which remains is that I see the progress bar only at the end after RunWorkerCompleted event done, and I don't see the advance any time ProgressChanged event called

Comment: @Programmer put this line  progress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage; inside Dispatcher.Invoke method. It should work then

Comment: Can you please edit your answer with sample code? 
I tried:
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action() => { progress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage; }); 

Inside ProgressChanged method but it doesn't work..

Comment: Thanks! And it should be inside ProgressChanged method- right?
Now, ProgressChanged method shall include only Dispatcher.Invoke implementation right?

Comment: @Programmer yes i already have updated that. feel free to accept the answer if it worked. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I still have an issue- now it threw exception on Dispatcher.Invoke - any idea why?

Comment: @Programmer what is the exception?

Comment: 'An unhandled exception of type System.StackOverflowException occurred in WindowsBase.dll make sure you do not have an infinite loop or infinite recursion'

Comment: @Programmer I can't replicate your exact situation but try this: Replace Invoke method with BeginInvoke  and then check

Comment: I did what you suggested and now I don't got an exception, but I again don't see the progress of the progress bar  (in addition, I added lock statement on currentStep variable)

Comment: @Programmer it seems like queuing problem on main thread. I'm not sure how many items are being executed on main thread in your code/context. One last thing I can suggest is to copy current dispatcher code and paste it in place of  backgroundWorker.ReportProgress((int)Math.Floor((decimal)(8*i))); line in DoWork method. (obviously in place of e.ProgressPercentage; put int)Math.Floor((decimal)(8*i)).)

Comment: still not perfect but it's a little better now. Thanks you!